# How do I influence link distance in 3d-force-graph?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, three.js, d3-force-directed

I am trying out the 3d Force Graph in [this package](https://github.com/vasturiano/3d-force-graph) and I am looking for ways to influence bond strength between nodes.  Either link width or length would be good, but I don't see anything in API that allows me to control or influence either.  What is the correct field of `Graph` to pass in link strenghts, one for each link?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a modified version of this [example](https://vasturiano.github.io/3d-force-graph/example/basic/) which applies a custom distance per link:

```js
const N = 300;
const gData = {
  nodes: [...Array(N).keys()].map(i => ({ id: i })),
  links: [...Array(N).keys()]
    .filter(id => id)
    .map(id => {

      var distance = (Math.random() < 0.2) ? 75 : 250;
      var width = (distance == 75) ? 4 : 0.2;

      return ({
        source: id,
        target: Math.round(Math.random() * (id-1)),
        width: width,
        distance: distance
      })
    })
};

const Graph = ForceGraph3D()
  (document.getElementById('3d-graph'))
    .graphData(gData)
    .linkWidth('width')
    .cameraPosition({ z: 600 })
    .d3Force("link", d3.forceLink().distance(d => d.distance))
    .d3Force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().theta(0.5).strength(-1));
```

```html
<head>
  <style> body { margin: 0; } </style>

  <script src="//unpkg.com/3d-force-graph"></script>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="3d-graph"></div>
</body>
```

---

In fact, to allow users to modify links parameters, the library simply uses the d3 [force](https://github.com/d3/d3-force#simulation_force) API. The only difference is the name of the accessor in the [3d-force-graph](https://github.com/vasturiano/3d-force-graph) library which is `.d3Force()` (instead of `.force()` in d3).

For instance, to modify the distance per link, we can add a `distance` attribute to each link data point (in addition to `source` and `target`) and then modify this distance as follow in the force layout (using the `d3Force` accessor):

```
.d3Force("link", d3.forceLink().distance(d => d.distance))
```

whereas in a d3 force layout we would have used:

```
.force("link", d3.forceLink().distance(d => d.distance))
```

which gives us:

```
const Graph = ForceGraph3D()
  (document.getElementById('3d-graph'))
    .graphData(gData)
    .linkWidth('width')
    // The link distance modification:
    .d3Force("link", d3.forceLink().distance(d => d.distance))
    // To make it prettier:
    .d3Force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().theta(0.5).strength(-1));
```

The strength can be adjusted the same way, using:

```
.d3Force("link", d3.forceLink().strength(d => d.strength))
```

---

In the example, I have given each link a distance which is randomly either 75 or 250. And to make it clear, I have given a bigger width to links with a smaller distance. The distribution of nodes in my demo is not perfect, and might need additional tuning.